# Create Percentage Sign Variable to use in Environment Variables

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables, path

In Windows 10, some environment variables actually use percentage signs to refer to paths.  For example, the PSModulePath environment variable looks like this (ignore the additional one I marked out):

[image]

and you'll notice that it uses percentage signs to refer to certain directories instead of hard-coded paths.  Suppose that I have several environment variables that I want to add, but I would like them to refer to custom directories of my own.  For example, if I wanted to add some folder named "Include" located in some custom directory to an environment variable, ideally all I would have to do is add this text to the corresponding environment variable:

```
%MyCustomDirectoryVariable%\Include
```

But, of course, there's a problem; I'm not sure if it's even possible to create my own percentage sign variables that can refer to specific directories!  **Is it possible for me to create my own custom percentage sign variable that the environment variables can properly interpret as a directory?**  Or if I want to add my own path to an environment variable, must it always be a hard-coded path?

Comment: But those "percentage sign variables" _are_ environment variables...

Comment: When working with the registry directly you have to take care to use the type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` instead of `REG_SZ` the GUI environment variable editor does this automatically. If you want to persistently (not just for the current session) set a variable in a batch use `setx /?`

Comment: @LotPings, would you be able to give an example of how to use setx to achieve this?  Everything I research just shows it being used to specifically modify the PATH environment variable, not how to create a new percentage sign one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the set - command.
Just open a commmand prompt and try:

> set myvar = c:\sourcecode\include\

After that you can use %myvar% where you need it.

Comment: That's a very bad idea - you'll have an environment var `myvar ` with a trailing space  and the content has also a leading space. To use this variable you'd have to include the space `%myvar %`. Preferred syntax is `set "myvar=c:\sourcecode\include\` but this answer totally misses OPs objective making a vartiable depending on another one.